# How is data passed to parent class without a constructor when inheriting List<T>? C#

Tags: c#, .net

I was going through a code that inherited `List<T>`. When the object was created for the child class that inherited `List<T>`, two values of type T were passed.

How did those two objects reach the parent class `List<T>`? As far as I know you need to have a constructor that passes parameters to parent's constructor using `:base()`, but in my case there wasn't any `base` specified anywhere.

Here are my classes

```
public class Person
{
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class PeopleCollection : List<Person>
{

}
```

Now say I have two objects of type `Person` named p1, p2

My concern is with the line below..

```
PeopleCollection people = new PeopleCollection { p1, p2 };
```

There is no constructor in `PeopleCollection` that takes a collection of Type Person. Yet two objects are passed.

What I want to know is that, is there a default behavior while inheriting `List<T>` that when you create an object for the class that inherits `List<T>`, it automatically adds values to the parent `List<T>`? if no then how is the above code working? Where are p1, and p2 stored since `PeopleCollection` doesn't have it's own collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This technique is called [Collection Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) and it's not related to constructors as mentioned in the question.

> Collection initializers let you specify one or more element
>   initializers when you initialize a collection type that implements
>   **IEnumerable** and has **Add** with the appropriate signature as an instance
>   method or an extension method. The element initializers can be a
>   simple value, an expression, or an object initializer. By using a
>   collection initializer, you do not have to specify multiple calls; the
>   compiler adds the calls automatically.

Comment: Maybe worth adding since it's not mentioned explicitly, this feature has nothing to do with constructors.